# Convert characters like © ƒ to its orignal form

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, watermark

I am receiving these Unknown characters on my PDF Water mark,

How can i convert them into original form ?

**This is the orignal Input:**

```
$pdf->Write(0, utf8_encode('àexception de') );
```

But in PDF it is showing me something like this:

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Contrary to popular believe, `utf8_encode()` is not a function to magically fix all encoding issues ever. It merely converts from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't `utf8_encode` the string. Make sure you're passing the string in an encoding the PDF library expects. Figure out what that is exactly. Read [What you need to know about encodings to work with text](http://kunststube.net/encoding).

Comment: Deceze you were fast. +1. Deleting mine :)

Comment: But its adding a " / " when its sees " ' "  in string

Comment: @Code What? Again, you have a simple encoding problem. Without more details I can't tell you how to fix that exactly. The best way for you to fix that is to *understand* encodings, for which you can start with the linked article.